# Unable to get the sources for my kernel

Tags: apt, software-sources

I am trying to get the sources for my kernel
Here is the source.list file

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe   
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe   
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe   
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted    
deb-src http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty restricted main universe  
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates restricted main universe    
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe   
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security restricted main universe  
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed restricted main universe

uname -r
3.19.0-25-generic
```

I am getting this error message

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)   
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
E:You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an apt-get update! 
I manually added the deb-src lines and I did not realize that I need to update the package list